# are ntp.org pools and time.windows.com safe from gps 2019 week rollover?

Tags: ntp, gps

Can anyone point to any public doc stating that pools from ntp.org and time.windows.com are safe from next thrusday gps week rollover ?

I am looking to something similar to this Red Hat KB

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4018911

thanks
g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's been a short discussion of the issue on the NTP Pool operators' forum. [They don't seem worried.](https://community.ntppool.org/t/gps-rollover-may-malfunction-on-or-after-april-6/1172)

> The expected impact is low.
>
> If any servers starts serving the wrong time, they will quickly be
>   removed from the system.
>
> Most clients should be recognizing the clearly bad time (very
>   different from the other signals they get, before their manufacturing
>   date, etc) and ignore the signal.
>
> Of course a server can serve bad time for some minutes before it gets
>   noticed by the monitoring system and DNS updated and clients might not
>   be well implemented.

As a community project you shouldn't expect anything like an official document.

Another reply to that post suggested that most GPS receivers already will handle the rollover and no action is expected to be required.

If time is critical to your operations, then you should have someone on call this weekend to check your NTP servers after 7 April 00:00 UTC.

Comment: thanks,  any news from microsoft folks?

Comment: From Microsoft? I haven't seen anythng at all.